# I'm blocked with simple issue, infinite loop

Tags: javascript

it is my **first question contribution** here so i **hope** it will be ok with all the rules. 
It is a **simple question**, i have **basic** knowledge of language, i have to **change values** every *array[2n]* when someone is enterying a value it will **multiply** the value they entered **by the values in the array**.

so : *tableau[1,2,3,4,5,..,100] must become : if user enter 4 tableau[4,2,12,4,20..]*

it is :

```js
tableau = new Array(100);
var userInput = prompt('give me a value');

for (i = 0; i < tableau.lengt; i++) {
  tableau[i] = i + 1;

  if (i = 0) {
    tableau[i] = i * userInput;
    console.log('voici mon tableau : [' + i + '] : ' + tableau[i]);
    var pair = i % 2;
    if (pair = 0) {

      tableau[i + 1] = tableau[i] * userInput;
      console.log('voici mon tableau : [' + i + '] : ' + tableau[i]);
    } else {
      console.log('voici mon tableau : [' + i + '] : ' + tableau[i]);
    }

  }
}
```

I had issue to implement my code, if you can give me some tips to be able to have a full block of it, i read the help but wasn't able to fix it :(.

So here is my issue, with this code i have an **infinite loop**, and i am not able to see what is happening because my browser crash.
I hope it is not a dumb question and as loop are different for everyone i couldn't find my solution.
thank you in advance

Comment: Surely this loop doesn't execute at all, since `tableau.lengt` isn't defined.

Comment: You have a typo on `tableau.length`. You have `tableau.lengt` and you are using `=` instead of `==` or `===` for comparison which is causing `i` to always be `0`.

Comment: ok i think you get my issue, i thought that {tableau = new Array(100);} would automatically give a lenght, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is different trouble on your code.

I made some correction, see live example below

```js
tableau = new Array(100);
var userInput = prompt('give me a value');

for (var i = 0; i < tableau.length; ++i) {
  var pair = i % 2;
  if (pair == 0) {
    tableau[i] = (i + 1) * userInput;
  } else {
    tableau[i] = i + 1;
  }
}

console.log(tableau)
```

Comment: thank you very much, i think i was too complicated for nothing, i didn't that we could console.log(tableau) to give all values of an array. 
i add a main loop because i would a print on each calcul and everything works. thank you everyone i will close the question now. 
very good first experience on stackoverflow, very quick answer !

Comment: @Lito40 You can also do `console.table(tableau)` to show an array

Answer (score 1):

You're using assignment operator '=' for comparison here. It should be

```
if (i == 0)
```

instead.
Otherwise, what you're doing is to set i to 0 every time, so the loop never ends, beause i only have the values 1 (at the end of the loop) and 0 again.
Same for

```
if (pair == 0) {
```

as well, of course.

Btw., a good practice to overcome this issue is to write

```
0 == i
```

instead. This way, if you forget the '=' there won't be any assignment to i happening (you will get an error message).

Answer (score 0):

**=** is used for assignment and **==** **||** **===** are used for comparison. In your if statement either use **==** or **===**  **.**  **=** will not work as it will always return true and hence the infinite loop.
This will be-

```
 if (i = 0) {
        //tableau[i] = i * userInput;
        //console.log('voici mon tableau : [' + i + '] : ' + tableau[i]);
        //var pair = i % 2;
        if (pair = 0) {
```

this

```
 if (i == 0) {
        //tableau[i] = i * userInput;
        //console.log('voici mon tableau : [' + i + '] : ' + tableau[i]);
        //var pair = i % 2;
        if (pair == 0) {
```